# What is the Regex for cloudformation IAM policy name

Tags: regex, aws-cloudformation

I am trying define a parameter for the IAM role name. Here's my parameter

```
         Type: String
         AllowedPattern: "arn:aws:iam::*$"
         ConstraintDescription: Must be an IAM policy ARN.
```

The IAM policy name is of the format - `arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber:policy/staging_test`

Here's the error I am getting 
`Parameter EnvDynamoDbPolicy failed to satisfy constraint:`

Comment: I guess you're looking for the pattern `^arn:aws:iam::.*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html#cfn-iam-policy-policyname), the RE2 (so also terraform and any other RE2-based software) regex is:

```
^arn:aws:iam::(\d{12})?:policy/[\w+=,.@-]{1,128}$
```

where the 12-digits account-id is actually optional while within the same account and the `:aws:` segment could hold a "partition" name other than AWS'. String must match from begin to end, of course.

Comment: The linked documentation no longer contains this regex. Is there a newer authoritative source for this information?

Comment: I think that is a publishing error as it is still mentioning "This parameter allows (through its regex pattern) a string of characters consisting..." . Maybe you can open a case to AWS and ask. I am still using that regex, though.

Comment: Case opened. Good call; the Pattern section is missing from multiple properties there that say they should have a regex.

Answer (score 1):

`*` in regex is not a "wildcard operator", it has a specific meaning (namely, zero or more of the preceding character/group).

The "description" of the rules that a custom IAM policy ARN must satisfy are:

1. Start with "arn:aws:iam::"
2. Followed by Account ID, which is 12 digits
3. Followed by ":policy/"
4. Followed by... at least one character?

So the regex pattern would be:

```
^arn:aws:iam::\d{12}:policy/.+
```

Which is exactly what the steps above describe. (You may need to escape the forward slashes with a backslash, depending on the regex engine used.)

Answer (score 0):

Was there anything after `Parameter EnvDynamoDbPolicy failed to satisfy constraint:`?

If you look at the `java.util.regex.Pattern`, which is what cloudformation uses for regex matching, I don't see them using the dollar sign.

[Here's a link to the docs that point to the java patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-regexes.html), and [Here's a link to the patterns themselves](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

I'm not a regex wizard, but it looks like if you just removed the dollar sign it would work. So...

**I haven't tested this, it's just a guess**

```
Type: String
AllowedPattern: "arn:aws:iam::*"
ConstraintDescription: Must be an IAM policy ARN.
```

---

It could also be the case for other people that have this problem that the name of their parameter doesn't meet the constraints.  [Here's a link to the constraint description](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html).

Comment: I tried it without the $ sign and this is the error I am still seeing -                                  
`                                                                                                                                      An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameter EnvDynamoDbPolicy failed to satisfy constraint: Must be an IAM policy ARN               
 `

Comment: The following Regex worked `AllowedPattern: "^arn:aws:iam::.*"`. But now i am getting `ARN Ref is not valid. (Service: AmazonIdentityManagement; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidInput` Error

Answer (score 0):

Cloudformation actually gives you the pattern in the events output, if an input fails for any reason. For example, if the policy value input to the template isn't correct, you'll get an error like -

```
validation error detected: Value '[the invalid value]' at 'role' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:iam::\d{12}:policy/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@\-_/]+
```

So, the regex you need in your case is arn:(aws[a-zA-Z-]*)?:iam::\d{12}:policy/?[a-zA-Z_0-9+=,.@-_/]+